# Enabling a textarea based on one of the radiobutton response

Tags: javascript

I am trying to enable `textarea` based on selection of one of the four `radio buttons.`

```
<div id="Response">
   <label><input type="radio" name="Radi4.19" value="Y" id="Radio_4.19_0">Yes</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="Radi4.19" value="N" id="Radio_4.19_1">No</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="Radi4.19" value="NS" id="Radio_4.19_2">Not Seen</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="Radi4.19" value="NA" id="Radio_4.19_3">Not Applicable</label>
</div>

<span id="responseSupplement">
  <div id="Comment">
   <label for="Comment">Comment:</label>
   <textarea name="comment" rows="6" style="width: 530px;" id="Comm4.19" placeholder="Enter comments here ..."></textarea>
   </div>

<div id="Observation">`
    <label for="Observation">Observation:</label>`
    <textarea name="observation" rows="6" disabled="disabled" id="Obs4.19" style="width: 530px;" placeholder="Enter text of observation here ..."></textarea>
</div>
</span>
```

I was able to create desired functionality based on binary choice:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function enable(val)
{if(val)document.f1.feedback.setAttribute("disabled",val)
else
document.f1.feedback.removeAttribute("disabled",val)}
</script>

<form name="f1" action="" >
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="green" onclick="enable(0)"/><label for="green">Positive</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="rating" value="0" id="red" onclick="enable(1)" /><label for="red">Negative</label><br />
<textarea name="feedback" rows="6" disabled style="width: 50%;" ></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: Cannot achieve the same for "four-choice" option. If user selects "No" then the textarea "Observation" which is originally "disabled" should become enabled.

Comment: For Yes, NA and NS - textarea "Observations" remains "disabled"

Comment: @Alexaander, Mabedan has given the exact solution for your requirement, refer the Fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/m5n6s/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the checked or unchecked status of the clicked radio button, for that you can pass `this` as the parameter of your event listener.

http://jsfiddle.net/m5n6s/

Comment: Thank you. But in your examples (works!) initial state of the textarea "Observation" is ENABLED. If I set textarea =disabled. then surely provided JS does not work.

Comment: Why not? http://jsfiddle.net/8my66/ it works for me... The Js will simply change that disabled attribute.

Comment: One more thing - if I have a number of textareas with their own id, what would be the solution in JS. Current solution refers to a specific textarea by its id (Obs401):                                                                                                       document.radioChange = function (button)
{if(button.checked ) {if (button.value === "N") {document.getElementById("Obs401"").removeAttribute("disabled")}
 else
 {document.getElementById("Obs401"").setAttribute("disabled",true)}}}